# How to Get Company Name for a Windows Service Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-service

In order to be able to easily detect which of a group of security products is installed on a machine, I would like to be able to filter the Powershell `Get-Service` output by the Company Name attached to the service, but that information is not included in the `Get-Service` output. I've also tried using a `Get-WmiObject` query in place of `Get-Service` and still no Company Name.

I know the information is available somehow because Process Explorer shows it.

Comment: Feeling thick this morning ... the answer is to use Get-Process which _does_ output the Company. Severfault wouldn't let me answer my own question yet.

Comment: Don't forget you can also use something like Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = 'SmcService'" to get the executable path for a given service, which you can then run Get-Process on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `Get-Process` and filter with `Where-Object` to list process with a specific Company Name:

`Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Company -eq "IBM" }`

Would return any process with a company name of `IBM` exactly.  You may also use any of the other comparison/regex operators to alter the fitlering:

`Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Company -like "*ymantec*" }`

Would return process with a company name containing `ymantec` anywhere in the string.